UserForm.Hide by name of the Userform
I have a workbook with several userforms, that open/close other userforms.
Previously I hardcoded it:
UserForm1.Hide

That worked.
Now I am trying to close them using the name of the userform.
Public Function Close_UserForm(ByVal UserForm_Name As String) As Boolean
    
    PrintSearchHistory "CLOSE", "Close_UserForm()", UserForm_Name
    If IsOpen_UserForm(UserForm_Name) = False Then
        Close_UserForm = True
        PrintSearchHistory "SUCCESS", "Close_UserForm()", UserForm_Name
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim obj As Object

    On Error Resume Next
        Set obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(UserForm_Name)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If obj Is Nothing Then
        ErrorShow 0, 10, UserForm_Name
        Exit Function
    End If
    obj.Hide
    Close_UserForm = True
    PrintSearchHistory "SUCCESS", "Close_UserForm()", UserForm_Name
    
End Function

PrintSearchHistory is a custom error handler, so is ErrorShow.
IsOpen_Workbook checks if the workbook is closed and skips the function if it is.
My problem is when Obj.Hide. is executed nothing happens to the userform.
I have the same function for Open_UserForm, with the only difference being Obj.Show instead of Obj.Hide. That function works.
All userforms are modeless and all userforms have several buttons to close the userforms: Always at least one X-Button and one CommandButton.
For each userform I have one function, which all Closing-Buttons call.
For example: Booking_UserForm has X-Button and Close_Button, which call Close_Booking.
Close_Booking has special functions for userform-handling and as the last function it has Close_UserForm "Booking_UserForm".
Private Sub CloseBooking()

    Set_UserFormSettings ConstBooking
    ClearBundleArray
    Activate_Workbook RMS_Name, Interface_Sheet
    Close_UserForm ConstBooking
    
End Sub

Using the X-Button works, but only because it is closed after the function is done.
Other things I tried:
Move Obj.Hide to the last line of the function.
Replace Obj.Hide with Unload Me.
Unload Obj (Using this caused a stack overflow by calling UserForm_QueryClose->Close_Workbook->UserForm_QueryClose etc.)

You are aware that Set obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(UserForm_Name) will just add another entry to the Userformscollection. It will not point to the userform you are after.

Not sure why you wouldn't simply do Set form = New MyUserForm and then work with that form instance, instead of dealing with default instances and global state bugs.

Not sure what you are after but in order to hide all open Userforms you could use the following code
Function hideAllUserforms()
    Dim frm
    ' Loop through all open Userforms
    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        frm.Hide
    Next frm
End Function

Per your description you should probaly adjust your code for what you call the x-button. I think you refer to the X in the top right-hand corner each form comes with and which allows the user to cancel it.
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                       , CloseMode As Integer)
    
    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
    
    ' Hide the Userform
    Hide

End Sub

If (and only if I think) you always use only the global default instance of your userforms you could use the following code to hide the userform by name
Function hideUserform(frmName As String)
    Dim frm
    ' Loop through all open Userforms
    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Name = frmName Then
            frm.Hide
            ' If you do not exit here this function will close all
            ' instances of the given userform with the name frmName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next frm
End Function

